# vlookup for blanks in Python

Tags: python, vlookup

I have 2 data set in Python I want to vlookup country on basis of it's State in second data set but only where if the orinal State column in the data 1 is blank I am trying to run loop example attached below.

[image]

Comment: yea but where are you looking up from? they are both labeled the same

Comment: i want output in df1 referencing df2(my mistake the left one is df2 the one with all country information filled in it )